# Ansible stdout lines result without brackets and quotes

Tags: ansible

How can I return from playbook stdout_lines without brackets and quotes?

Any information I read about this isn’t working ,

This is my code:

```
  - name: Tested unit information
    command: cat "{{ location }}/info.txt"
    register: sys_info
  - debug: 
      msg: "{{ sys_info.stdout_lines }}"
```

This is my output:

```
    "msg": [
        "Serial Number: Test12345",
        "Technician Name: Team",
        "Custom Serial Number: Test12345",
        "System Part Number: xxxx",
        "Rev: A10",
        "Last Rev: A10",
        "Paka Number: Auto",
        "Ip Address: 1.1.1.1"
    ]
}
```

This what I want to get:

```
msg:
    Serial Number: Test12345
    Technician Name: Team
    Custom Serial Number: Test12345
    System Part Number: xxxx
    Rev: A10
    Last Rev: A10
    Paka Number: Auto
    Ip Address: 1.1.1.1
```

I would appreciate any information or suggestion on how to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**

Use *stdout* instead of *stdout_lines* and use *yaml* callback instead of *default*. Then

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sys_info.stdout }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  msg: |-
    Serial Number: Test12345
    Technician Name: Team
    Custom Serial Number: Test12345
    System Part Number: xxxx
    Rev: A10
    Last Rev: A10
    Paka Number: Auto
    Ip Address: 1.1.1.1
```

---

**Details**

---

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat info.txt
Serial Number: Test12345
Technician Name: Team
Custom Serial Number: Test12345
System Part Number: xxxx
Rev: A10
Last Rev: A10
Paka Number: Auto
Ip Address: 1.1.1.1
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat test.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Tested unit information
      command: cat info.txt
      register: sys_info
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sys_info.stdout_lines }}"
```

---

What you see depends on the [DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback). The *default* callback format is JSON

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook test.yml

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Serial Number: Test12345",
        "Technician Name: Team",
        "Custom Serial Number: Test12345",
        "System Part Number: xxxx",
        "Rev: A10",
        "Last Rev: A10",
        "Paka Number: Auto",
        "Ip Address: 1.1.1.1"
    ]
}
```

If you want to create plain text from the list use [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for line in sys_info.stdout_lines %}
          {{ line }}
          {% endfor %}
```

, or simply *join* the lines

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sys_info.stdout_lines|join('\n') }}"
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook test.yml

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Serial Number: Test12345\nTechnician Name: Team\nCustom Serial Number: Test12345\nSystem Part Number: xxxx\nRev: A10\nLast Rev: A10\nPaka Number: Auto\nIp Address: 1.1.1.1\n"
}
```

Use callback *yaml* to get what you want

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook test.yml

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    Serial Number: Test12345
    Technician Name: Team
    Custom Serial Number: Test12345
    System Part Number: xxxx
    Rev: A10
    Last Rev: A10
    Paka Number: Auto
    Ip Address: 1.1.1.1
```